# split emacs window horizontally and keep each at [80] characters

Tags: emacs

When I run `C-x 3`, I'd like to have each resulting emacs window be 80 characters wide (my default), making the total emacs frame 80 characters wider. The default behavior is to split the window into two smaller windows.

I'm using the emacs terminology where a "frame" is what you typically refer to as a "window" in a GUI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to do something like

```
 (defun layout-for-cobol ()
   "Lay out the frame as two 80-column windows across"
   (interactive)
   (when window-system
     (require 'frame-cmds)
     (set-frame-width (selected-frame) 160)
     (with-selected-window (get-mru-window)
       (delete-other-windows)
       (split-window-right 80))))
```

`frame-cmds.el` can be found at http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/frame-cmds.el

You could either call that with `M-x layout-for-cobol` (or pick a nicer name ☺) or bind it with `(when window-system (global-set-key (kbd "C-x 3") 'layout-for-cobol))` in your `.emacs` file.

(The `(when window-system …)` forms are to suppress error messages when you try to resize a terminal-mode Emacs.)

Comment: Fantastic! 
I just had to add a couple close-parens at the end.
I also had to download frame-fns.el from here:
http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/frame-fns.el

Comment: One follow-up question: How do I keep frame-cmds.el and frame-fns.el up-to-date?

Comment: Personally, I don't actually track changes in those ☹ I have them in `~/.emacs.d/`, and I manually update files in there only if I find something breaks, or gets included in Fedora's defaults … and shame on me, I cut N pasted wrong? adjusting to correct